# jQuery hide the divs based on the classes getting from server

Tags: jquery

I have 3 `div` blocks. Based on the response getting from my AJAX request, I want to show or hide the specific block. Suppose I have gotten the response in JSON format like this:

```
var response = [{
    "class":[
        "firstBlock",
        "secondBlock"
    ]
}]
```

```js
<div class="mianBlock">
    <div class="firstBlock">
        div content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="secondBlock">
        div content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="thirdBlock">
        div content goes here
    </div>
 </div>
```

Using jQuery, how do I hide the 2 blocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the JSON to build a selector from the returned class names. Try this:

```
var selector = '.' + response[0].class.join(', .');
$(selector).hide();
```

```js
var response = [{
    "class": [
        "firstBlock",
        "secondBlock"
    ]
}]

var selector = '.' + response[0].class.join(', .');
$(selector).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mianBlock">
    <div class="firstBlock">
        div content goes here - firstBlock
    </div>
    <div class="secondBlock">
        div content goes here - secondBlock
    </div>
    <div class="thirdBlock">
        div content goes here - thirdBlock
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

js

```
 var response =  [
   {
      "class":[
         "firstBlock",
         "secondBlock"
      ]
   }
]
 $(".mianBlock >div").show();
$.each(response, function(i,items) {   
    $.each(items.class, function(j,value) {
        var element=".mianBlock ."+value;
           console.log(element); 
        $(element).hide();
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="mianBlock">
    <div class="firstBlock">
        div content goes here - firstBlock
    </div>
    <div class="secondBlock">
        div content goes here - secondBlock
    </div>
    <div class="thirdBlock">
        div content goes here - thirdBlock
    </div>
</div>
```

[js Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/3yk97g0w/2/)